# Arduino: Error al querer aumentar valor en un switch case

Tags: arduino

Tengo el problema que estoy en un switch case que al ser presionado por un push button ira cambiando de valores, pero si no lo presiono muestro una animación de espera, así que cree una función para esa animación y la metí en el caso 0 de mi swith case, pero al ejecutarlo la animación se queda aun dándole al botón y si quito esa función del mi caso 0 funciona perfectamente, alguien me podría ayudar a ver porque no funciona.

````
switch (contador)
  {
    case 0:
      on(1000);
      break;


void on (int tiempo) {
  for (int letra = 6; letra >= 0; letra--) {
    digitalWrite(letra, HIGH);
    delay(tiempo);
    digitalWrite(letra, LOW);
    delay(tiempo);

  }
}```
````

Comment: Quiero ayudarte, pero la verdad que no entendí nada bien tu problema, puedes expresarlo de una manera más clara, o con mayor detalle.

Comment: La animación tarda 12 segundos en ejecutarse. Mientras no acabe no va a hacer caso a nada el arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo Nacho, la animación es muy larga, y durante todo ese tiempo (12 segundos), nada más funciona.

Tienes que implementar tu `loop()` sin usar `delay`, pues mientras está en delay, nada más funciona, y si el delay es muy largo, Arduino se va a resetear.

La solución general para no usar delay es llevar la cuenta de donde estas y cuanto tiempo ha pasado. Vamos a mostrar como hacer el `blink` sin delay. Este código encenderá el LED 6 veces solamente; luego parara.

```
int pulsos = 12; // 6 encendidos + 6 apagados.
int duracion = 1000;
```

Estas dos variables nos dan el número de pulsos en cada animación.

También tenemos una variable que nos da el tiempo de comienzo del actual pulso:

```
unsigned long start;
```

`Setup` asigna una valor inicial a la variable `start`

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  start = millis();
}
```

En `loop`, en cada iteración calculamos la duración del último encendido/apagado del LED. Una vez que sobrepasa la duración requerida, cambia el pin de salida y vuelva a inicializar `start` con la hora actual.

```
void loop() {
  unsigned long now = millis();
  int len = now - start;

  if (len > duracion && pulsos) {
    Serial.println("click ...");
    start = now;
    pulsos--;
  }
  
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, pulsos % 2);
  //
  // Aqui va el resto del código que lee botones,
  // controla relays, activa motores, etc.
  //
}
```

Para saber si toca encender o apagar el LED, examinamos `pulsos`. Cuando este es impar, el módulo da `1` y `digitalWrite` enciende el LED. Cuando es impar, lo apaga.

Mientras el LED pestaña, podemos hacer otras cosas. Como ejemplo, puse un `Serial.print`, pero también puede ser la lectura de un botón o cualquier otra acción necesaria.

Comment: Gracias, con eso lo pude resolver, e investigando.